# how to append image and header using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, append

I have this to data I got from ajax request and I want to make them appear on the same line; Here is my code

html

```
<div id="one"></div>
```

jquery

```
$getJSON(...,function(data){

$("#one").append("<img src="+ data.image_icon +">"+"<h3>" +data.title"</h3>")

})
```

when I do that the items dont appear on the same line. What can i do to make both appear on the same line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block;` for the element `h3` and give singlequotes(`'`) in correct place like below

```js
var image_icon = 'http://placehold.it/140x158';
var title = 'title';
$("#one").append("<img src='" + image_icon + "'>" + "<h3>" + title + "</h3>");
```

```css
h3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
   img {
     display: inline-block;
   }
```

in your css

Answer (score 1):

`h3` is a blocked element.

You have to overwrite the `display` property.

Try this:

```
h3 { display: inline-block; }
img { display: inline-block; }
```